# Select user from all groups they belong in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am going to select all the user from groups they belong.

Database is this.

```
Classroom Table // This is the GROUP .. or Classroom Group
>classroom_id (pk)
>classroom_name
>classroom_description
>instructor_id


CLassroom Members Table
>classroom_id (fk)
>account_id (fk)

User Table
>account_id (pk)
>account_name
```

..i already tested some.. but can you please give me a little advice or sql logic

Comment: The question is unclear (to me, at least). Can you please share some sample data and the result you're trying to get?

Comment: Where's your SQL statement so far? Furthermore, I don't see any "group" here.

Comment: I guess you need to check out JOIN's and ORDER BY.

Comment: i have used inner join .. i updated the tables above.

Comment: The situation is >> i am the instructor, i want to select * my student joined in my created classroom. Student may join  classroom in any other instructor, but i want to select all the student who joins in my classroom.. << is that clear enough? @Mureinik

Comment: This looks like a very basic query with inner joins and you say you tried this. I can hardly imagine where you got this wrong. Did you get a syntax error or a wrong result? Maybe you should post your query and ask us to look at it for you to learn from our answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from User as u

Join Classroom Members as cm 
on u.account_id=cm.account_id 

join Classroom as c 
on cm.classroom_id=c.classroom_id

order by c.classroom_id desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.account_name,c.classroom_name,c.classroom_description
from  CLassroom_Members_Table b
join User_Table a
on b.account_id=a.account_id 
join Classroom_Table c
on b.classroom_id= c.classroom_id 
Where instructor_id=1
```

This gives the total details of the students in classroom where instructor_id=1

### Does this helps you....

Thanks.

Please mark as answer or vote this if it helps you